# Do the upvotes gained on ELU meta affect your reputation?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was just wondering whether my upvoted questions or answers on ELU meta affect my reputation. If they don't, would we be able to make this a feature?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [it's already explicitly answered on the help pages](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta): "Votes on meta do not affect your reputation." As the help pages are the first place someone should look to try to find an answer to this question, having the answer duplicated on Meta is unlikely to be very useful for the community.

Answer (score 12):

Questions and answers on Meta do not earn you reputation. The only exception, network wide, is questions on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), the network meta.

There is a reason for this.

Reputation relates to your knowledge of the site's subject matter. Meta is not related to that subject, so the reputation does not count. MSE is different because Meta **is** the area of expertise.

Additionally, with things like Feature Requests, downvoting is a way to show disagreement, and the last thing you want to do is propose a disliked question or answer and then be punished for voicing it by losing a lot of reputation... or to be punished for downvoting answer posts you don't like.

Users should feel free to voice their opinions on Meta without worrying about whether those opinions are popular.

As such, voting on Meta does not **and should not** affect your reputation.

Related on MSE:

[Why don't Meta upvotes count?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256625/why-dont-meta-upvotes-count)

More info on [this help page](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: Fair enough! Thanks for explaining :)

Answer (score -11):

It doesn't. I know this because a friend and I tested it. They asked a question on meta and I upvoted it and they didn't receive any reputation points. I agree with Louie Bnouie though and think that this should become a feature.

Comment: I suspect this has been downvoted because you have admitted targeted voting -- voting for a *person's* posts because of who they are, not voting on the *post* and its own merits. That's [not a good thing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219565/is-there-a-canonical-vote-for-the-content-not-the-user-post-on-se). Don't do it.

Comment: I agree with Andrew that you shouldn't collude with your buddy, but if you were just doing it to test the software, I don't think it's a big issue. I didn't doenvote for the collusion. I downvoted the idea of "think this should become a feature". I don't want Meta to effect reputation, for exactly the reasons that connection was removed by SE which Louie describes in his answer.

Comment: No, sorry @DanBron it **is** a big issue, even on Meta. It must not happen.

Comment: @AndrewLeach the question in question might have merited the up vote and the only test was to check if it gave reputation. Which could have happened after the fact. Anyways that's guesswork. I am down voting this because I think meta votes shouldn't affect reputation.